# Android animation properties

Tags: android, android-animation

I have a fairly simple Activity that has 3 dots within a ViewPager.  When the user slides to a new view I want the newly swiped to page's dot to animate itself larger while the previous pages dot should deflate.  The issue is that after swiping over to the 3rd(and final) page, the dots all begin animating improperly
i.e: when I swipe from dot 3 to dot 2, dot 3 will shrink, dot 2 will grow, and dot 1 will also shrink and after that the same pattern repeats with the correct dot inflating, but the other 2 will both deflate.

The java code is fairly simple and I don't think it is an issue there, but rather an issue in my animation code. 
I have read other questions and answers on SO about creating a similar system, and I have read this article regarding the animations xml properties but I worry about it's accuracy due to the date.
http://graphics-geek.blogspot.com/2011/08/mysterious-behavior-of-fillbefore.html
Here is link to the look I am trying to achieve[animated dots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ML5B.png)

```
//load animations
    final Animation markerGrow = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.marker_scale_up);
    final Animation markerShrink = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.marker_scale_down);


    //array for the 'dots'
    final ImageView[] markers = {(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.page1),(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.page2),(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.page3)};
    //inflate first 'dot' by default
    markers[0].startAnimation(markerGrow);

     @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            markers[oldPageId].startAnimation(markerShrink);
            markers[position].startAnimation(markerGrow);
            oldPageId = position;
            System.out.println("New selected marker = " + oldPageId);

            }
        }
```

The XML of the animations:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set android:shareInterpolator="false"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillBefore="false"
android:fillAfter="true"
android:fillEnabled="true">
<scale
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:toXScale="2"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:toYScale="2"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="250" />
</set>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set android:shareInterpolator="false"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillBefore="false"
android:fillAfter="true"
android:fillEnabled="true">
<scale
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXScale="2"
    android:toXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="2"
    android:toYScale="1"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:duration="250" />
</set>
```

Also the XML of the 'dot' which is just a circle

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/circle"
        android:id="@+id/page1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/page2"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/page2"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="false"
       />
```

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was that the my inflate/deflate animation both had the same properties for the following attributes:

```
android:fillBefore="false"
android:fillAfter="true"
android:fillEnabled="true"
```

While what I needed to do for the scale up animation was:

```
android:fillBefore="false"
android:fillAfter="true"
android:fillEnabled="true"
```

And for the scale down animation:

```
android:fillBefore="true"
android:fillAfter="false"
android:fillEnabled="true"
```